# How to make Soulseek portable

Tags: external-hard-drive, portable

Is it possible to run Soulseek portably from an external hard drive? The main problem I foresee is that Soulseek uses local paths to "Documents and Settings," which means it can't be portable unless I'm copying those files every time.

I've tried RegRapper, but it seems that it's not possible to map the "Documents and Settings" folder to the external hard drive.

How can I make portable Soulseek work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a portable version in testing [at PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/node/23215). Please see the entire post before using it.